# Relation between a group action and its transitive constituents

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathfrak{S}_X$ the symmetric group of $X$. Let $G$ be a group and suppose we have a homomorphism
$$\phi:G\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_X.$$
For every $x\in X$, let $\omega_x:G\rightarrow E$ be defined by $\omega_x(g)=\phi_g(x)$, for all $g\in G$. Then for every $x\in X$ the mapping
$${}^x\phi:G\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{\omega_x(G)},\,g\mapsto\phi_g|_{\omega_x(G)},$$
is a group homomorphism: i.e. $\omega_x(G)$ is a homogenous $G$-set.

What is the relation between the group $\text{Im}(\phi)$ and the family of groups $(\text{Im}({}^x\phi))_{x\in X}$? Is there a way to identify/embed $\text{Im}(\phi)$ with/into $\prod_{x\in X}\text{Im}({}^x\phi)$?

Comment: What is $\;E\;$ ?

Comment: That's supposed to be an $X$. Sorry! Fixed.

Comment: Fine, change it in your question.

Comment: Yes, ${\rm Im}(\phi)$ is a subdirect product of the orbit images. It would perhaps make more sense to take a single $x$ from each orbit rather than all $x \in X$.

Comment: Why don't you use standard terminology? The sets $w_x(G)$ are known as the orbits of the action, and the groups ${\rm Im}(^x\phi)$ are the images of the induced orbit actions, usually called the orbit images.

Comment: $E$ should be turned into $X$ also in the definition of $\omega_x$.